# php compare todays date with dates in (multi-dimensional) array?

Tags: php, arrays, date, multidimensional-array

I have an array of dates, I was wondering if it was possible to search an array and remove any items which are BEFORE todays date, and keep the rest?

Here's my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-07-14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-08-31
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-09-15
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-10-12
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-10-16
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-10-19
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-10-23
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-10-26
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-10-30
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-09-07
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-08-14
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-08-24
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-09-11
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-09-28
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2013-10-05
        )

)
```

Comment: What about looping throgh and comparing dates with actual required data and build a new filtered array?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly possible using a number of very simple techniques, most of them simply involving a loop. Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

```
$buffer = array();
foreach ($dates as $element) {
    if (strtotime($element['date']) >= time()) {
        $buffer[] = $element;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about looping throgh and comparing dates with actual required data and build a new filtered array?

```
$newarray = array();
foraeach($array as $data)
{
     if($data['date'] >= $yourdate)
     {
         $newarray] = $data;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`array_walk` function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-walk.php) lets you define a callback to run on every item in an array.

Comment: `array_filter` is a lot more apropos here, don't you think?

Comment: You're right, I forgot about that one. Seems a perfect fit for me.